# UIImageView setImage While UIScrollView is Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying to set the image property of a UIImageView while a UIScrollView is scrolling.  It seems like the image sets just fine but it only will show up in the image view once scrolling completes.

Not really required, but for what it's worth here is the code that I'm using.  This code is called on the main thread, after the image data finishes downloading and the image object is created.

```
[imageView setImage:image];
```

Is there a way to set the image property and have the image appear while scrolling is still going on?

Comment: Yes but *where* are you saying that code?

Comment: On the main thread after the image data finishes downloading and the image object is created.  Updated question for clarity.

Comment: Well there's your problem. The main thread isn't called until the scrolling is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only chance to run any code while the scroll view is scrolling is the UIScrollView delegate's `scrollViewDidScroll:`. So you must implement that and use it to check whether there's a new image value and set the image if there is.

Comment: I don't think this is answering their question. The problem they are having is that `imageView.image = newImage` called on a main thread isn't visible to the user until the UIScrollView stops scrolling. I'm hunting down for a solution on the same issue.

Comment: @TengL Fair enough, you might want to pose this as a new and different question.